# Unable to Start/Run Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I created a new Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015. I'm able to build successfully and I have cordova installed and the visual studio android emulators as well. But when I click start or click F5 it shows the message:
"unable to start debugging. the startup project could not be launched. The startup project can be changed by selecting 'set as startup project' command from right click in the menu explorer. Additionally make sure its debug settings are correctly configured in project properties". What can I do to solve this issue??

My startup project is setup correctly. I also won't give me the option to select the emulator when i click the down arrow next to start. Please help

Comment: At the begging try to run the project in debug mode with Ripple emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so the way I got it working is by doing this:

1. Close all VS instances
2. go to C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools
3. rename CoreCon folder to CoreCon2
4. Launch VS again.

Comment: Hi Ismael -- I am working on Visual Studio team and would like to see corrputed CoreCon cache. If you still have the folder CoreCon2, can you zip its content and share it?

Comment: Yes I do I have it, how can I share it?

Comment: Please zip it and share it from OneDrive/Dropbox -- you can share just one file and post link here. I will tell you when I download it, so you can remove the link :)

Comment: Thanks Ismael! I got it... You can remove the share.

Comment: Call him Ismael, master of Android debugging. Thanks, Dude.

Comment: I renamed CoreCon folder to CoreCon2 but when I again run the project system automatically create new CoreCon folder.  How ti prevent CoreCon folder creation.

Comment: The same solution worked for me on VS2017 Final. Seems as if this is still an issue sometimes.